# googleway, the radar argument is now deprecated

Tags: r, googleway

Attempting to use googleway package in r to list retirement villages within a specified radius of a location. Get the radar argument is now deprecated error message and null results as a consequence.

````
library(googleway)
a <- google_places(location = c(-36.796578,174.768836),search_string = "Retirement Village",radius=10000, key = "key")
a$results$name
```

#Would expect this to give me retirement villages within 10km radius, instead get error message

```> library(googleway)
> a <- google_places(location = c(-36.796578,174.768836),search_string = "Retirement Village",radius=10000, key = "key")
The radar argument is now deprecated
> a$results$name
NULL
```
````

Comment: Have you provided an API key?

Comment: yes I have, replaced with 'key' here

Comment: Your code works for me. I think you need to go into the google cloud platform and enable the places API for your key.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've written, and that 'message' you get is not an error, it's a message, but it probably should be removed - I've made an [issue to remove it here](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/205)

```
a <- google_places(
  location = c(-36.796578,174.768836)
  , search_string = "Retirement Village"
  , radius = 10000
  , key = "key"
  )

place_name( a ) 

# [1] "Fairview Lifestyle Village"                       "Eastcliffe Retirement Village"                   
# [3] "Meadowbank Retirement Village"                    "The Poynton - Metlifecare Retirement Village"    
# [5] "The Orchards - Metlifecare Retirement Village"    "Bupa Hugh Green Care Home & Retirement Village"  
#  [7] "Bert Sutcliffe Retirement Village"                "Grace Joel Retirement Village"                   
#  [9] "Bupa Remuera Retirement Village and Care Home"    "7 Saint Vincent - Metlifecare Retirement Village"
# [11] "Remuera Gardens Retirement Village"               "William Sanders Retirement Village"              
# [13] "Puriri Park Retirement Village"                   "Selwyn Village"                                  
# [15] "Aria Bay Retirement Village"                      "Highgrove Village & Patrick Ferry House"         
# [17] "Settlers Albany Retirement Village"               "Knightsbridge Village"                           
# [19] "Remuera Rise"                                     "Northbridge Residential Village"
```

Are you sure the API key you're using is enabled on the Places API?

Comment: Whoops, I could have sworn I did that but I see I didn't. Many thanks for the quick fix